# How to get management groups and subscriptions from different AAD tenant?

Tags: python, azure, subscription, azure-sdk-python, azure-management-groups

### Azure

I have two AAD(Azure Active Directory) in my account.

Entities in first AAD: `['Tenant Root Group', 'group A', 'subGroup B', 'Microsoft Partner Network', 'subscription 2']`

Entities in second AAD: `['Tenant Root Group', 'subscription 3']`

### Python

I'm trying to use python azure SDK to get `management groups` and `subscriptions` per `directory`.

The code below can list entities in first directory, but other entities in second directory does not listed as my expectation.

Does anyone know how to get all entities in both directories?

#### Code

```py
from azure.mgmt.managementgroups import ManagementGroupsAPI
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import UserPassCredentials


def get_entities(credentials):
    mgmt_groups_api = ManagementGroupsAPI(credentials)
    entities = mgmt_groups_api.entities.list()
    entity_infos = [entity for entity in entities]
    entity_names = [entity.display_name for entity in entity_infos]
    print(entity_names)


def main():
    credentials = UserPassCredentials(
        'account',
        'password',
    )
    get_entities(credentials)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

`['Group A', 'subGroup B', 'subGroup C', 'subscription 1', 'subscription 2']`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python API, but you'll basically need to specify the AAD tenant id to the credentials object so it authenticates against the correct tenant. You'll need to do the process twice, once for each directory.

Comment: Hi @juunas, I am using UserPassCredential as above. But like you said, if I could have a list of tenant id and then change the way to get credential. After that, repeatedly do get entities for each directory then I can get what I need. I think the problem becomes 'how to get a list of AAD tenant id', I'll survey how to do it. Thanks for your response 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @juunas for pointing out what this question really need and @Joy Wang provide an API solution to get tenant list by account.

### API solution

Thanks @juunas again, by using [Tenants - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) API we can easily listing tenants. (For more detail please take a look at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068729/10951158).)

I think it is a great general way to solve this question.

### Azure SDK for Python solution

Fortunately, I found `Azure SDK for Python` have provide [SubscriptionClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.subscriptionclient?view=azure-python#tenants) which allow me to list tenants programmatic.

This is how I list tenants in Python:

```py
def get_tenants() -> [TenantIdDescription]:
    credentials = UserPassCredentials(
        'account',
        'password',
    )
    sub_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
    tenants = sub_client.tenants.list()
    return tenants
```

#### Combine [SubscriptionClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.subscriptionclient?view=azure-python#tenants) into origin code

```
from azure.mgmt.managementgroups import ManagementGroupsAPI
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import UserPassCredentials

azure_account = ''
azure_pwd = ''

def get_credential(tenant_id: str = None):
    if tenant_id:
        return UserPassCredentials(
            azure_account,
            azure_pwd,
            tenant=tenant_id
        )
    else:
        return UserPassCredentials(
            azure_account,
            azure_pwd,
        )


def get_entities(tenant_id=None):
    credentials = get_credential(tenant_id)

    mgmt_groups_api = ManagementGroupsAPI(credentials)
    entities = mgmt_groups_api.entities.list()
    entity_infos = [entity for entity in entities]
    entity_names = [entity.display_name for entity in entity_infos]
    print(f'    entities: {entity_names}')


def get_tenants():
    credentials = get_credential()
    sub_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
    tenants = sub_client.tenants.list()
    return tenants


def main():
    tenants = get_tenants()

    i = 0
    print('[tenant list]')
    for tenant in tenants:
        print(f'tenant {i}:')
        print(f'    name:     {tenant.display_name}')
        print(f'    id:       {tenant.tenant_id}')
        get_entities(tenant.tenant_id)
        print()
        i = i + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### output

```
[tenant list]
tenant 0:
    name:     tenant1
    id:       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    entities: ['Tenant Root Group', 'group A', 'subGroup B', 'Microsoft Partner Network', 'subscription 2']

tenant 1:
    name:     tenant2
    id:       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    entities: ['Tenant Root Group', 'subscription 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @juunas's comment is correct, you need to specify the tenant when you use the credential.

> I think the problem becomes 'how to get a list of AAD tenant id'

You could use this REST API - [`Tenants - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list#code-try-0) to get the tenants for your account.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01
```

After getting the tenant id, specify the tenant in the user credential, make sure you used a work account without MFA(organization account, not personal account), the user credential uses the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) which will not work with personal account.

Comment: Hi @Joy Wang, thanks for your response. I found that Azure SDK for Python provider a way to list all tenants in my account. I'll post my code later.
[Azure SDK for Python - SubscriptionClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.subscriptionclient?view=azure-python#tenants)

Comment: @someone This is also right, the point is that you need to list management groups with different tenants. The sdk calls the [Management Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementgroups/list) api, it will list the management groups depends on the token(the token will include the tenant id in its cliaim) you provided i.e. the user credential, the code uses the credential to get the token.